# Origin of quote: "If you wish to speak or hear about God, renounce your own body..."

Tags: reference-request, origin

I've been reading *Orthodox Dogmatic Theology* by Protopresbyter Michael Pomazansky and encountered this quote attributed to St. Basil the Great:

> If you wish to speak or hear about God, renounce your own body,
>   renounce your bodily senses, pass over the seasons of the year, their
>   orderly arrangements, the adornments of the earth; stand above the
>   ether, traverse the stars, their splendor, grandeur, the profit which
>   they provide for the whole world, their good order, brightness,
>   arrangement, movement, and the bond or distance between them. Having
>   passed through all this in your mind, go about heaven and, standing
>   above it, with your thought alone, observe the beauties which are
>   there: the armies of angels, which are above the heavens, the chiefs
>   of the archangels, the glory of the Dominions, the presiding of the
>   Thrones, the Powers, Principalities, Authorities. Having gone past all
>   this and left below the whole of creation in your thoughts, raising
>   your mind beyond the boundaries of it, present to your mind the
>   essence of God, unmoving, unchanging, unalterable, dispassionate,
>   simple, incomplex, indivisible, unapproachable light, unutterable
>   power, infinite magnitude, resplendent glory, most desired goodness,
>   immeasurable beauty that powerfully strikes the wounded soul, but
>   cannot worthily be depicted in words.

Does anyone know where it came from?

Comment: Wow, St Basil's works take up 4 volumes in the *Patrologia Graecae*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this quote is from a Homily by St. Basil titled [*On Faith*](https://afkimel.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/st-basil-the-great-homily-on-faith/), specifically *Fide 1*, which can be found in the larger work [*On Christian Doctrine and Practice*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881414581).

> De fide, Mark DelCogliano writes, “is one of the classic expressions of [Basil’s] Trinitarian doctrine” (On Christian Doctrine and Practice, p. 227).